# React Native ScrollView not paginating in a perfectly aligned manner

Tags: react-native

I want to be able to scroll horizontally and have each card show up in the middle of the screen, but the pagination is not being perfectly aligned. For example, when I scroll to the next card, I see a portion of the next card.

```js
export default BookingScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const scrollRef = useRef(React.createRef) 
    const [animation] = useState(new Animated.Value(0))    

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.card}>
                <ScrollView
                    pagingEnabled
                    horizontal
                    scrollEventThrottle={16}
                    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    ref={scrollRef}
                    style={styles.scrollView}
                    contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollViewContent}
                    onScroll={Animated.event([
                        {
                            nativeEvent: {
                                contentOffset: {
                                    x: animation,
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ])}
                >
                    <FlatList 
                        data={items}
                        renderItem={({ item, index }) => 
                            <Card
                                item={item} 
                                index={index} 
                                navigation={navigation}                     
                            />
                        }
                        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
                        contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListContent}
                        horizontal={true}
                        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
                    /> 
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        width: width * 0.90,
    },
    card: {
        flex: 7,
        width: '100%',  
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center', 
    },
    cardContent: {
        width,   
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',         
    },
    scrollView: {
        width,
    },
    flatListContent: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',        
    }
})
```

Card is a simple, rectangular component with some margin on each side.

Card.js

```js
export default Card = ({ item, index, navigation }) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        width,
        margin: 10,
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any `ScrollView`'s props should work on `FlatList`, including `pagingEnabled`. You can achieve a horizontal list with pagination by using `FlatList` alone.

```js
// The width here is the screen's width as this is a horizontal list, and each item's width of the list should also be to the screen's width.
const width = SCREEN_WIDTH;

<FlatList
  horizontal
  pagingEnabled
  bounces={false}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  getItemLayout={(data, index) => (
      { length: width, offset: width * index, index }
  )}
  data={...}
  renderItem={...}
  keyExtractor={...}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I work with this and found that you can't use `ScrollView` and `FlatList` together(just need paging).
If you need paging just use FlatList and its props named `onEndReached`.
For more information visit this link
[FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist)